# A warning message in on office js dialog while opening a application in dialog in installed word and outlook

Tags: office365, office-js

when i am trying to open a application in dialog a warning message is coming upon the dialog that

> This add-in is not responding. close this warning dialog to keep it running or click "restart" to try again

and sometimes dialog is closing automatically with giving a warning

> Some other add-in you trying to open is not responding properly".
>   error images are below. please suggest.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is that add-in? What are you even asking?

Comment: it is a office js add-in build for outlook and word offce365 while i am opening the add-in i am getting above add-inif you have any solution or hints for this please help.

Comment: Although your question does not provide enough details, I would speculate that the add-in takes longer than 10 seconds to load. Check the Diagnostic Tools in VS for long calls; put breakpoints inside the code and execute line by line to see the IDE measurement for each execution.

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues with opening links in the dialog api that load insecure content.  For instance i had a custom built OAuth provider that also had olark chat on it.  Something about the way that loaded on there caused me a similar issue, i believe they were loading some image content or something from a non https link.  Check and see what all you are loading in the dialog api.

Can you load an otherwise blank page from the same domain?  if yes then start adding your start up scripts back one at a time till you hit your issue.

Comment: Thanks stewart,i am looking into the issue,regarding your last suggestion i want to tell that my app is a huge app cannot able to load file one by one it is not feasible idea and i am trying to open another app in office dialog through sso login.

Comment: sure i get that.  I just meant it as a debugging trick to try and find the offending script or content.  I understand that these things aren't always an options for everyone.